# Verifying existance of a node in xml through java

Tags: java

this is the bottom
        private static String getTagValue(String sTag, Element eElement)
        {
            NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

```
        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'verify'? Just see if the node is there? or do you need to check the nodes value?

Comment: when i enter the account number,my java program must read the input and verify the input value with the xml file given above..for example,if i enter 1111 when java request to enter account number,the java program must check if 1111 exist in that xml file or not,if found,my java program must go to the following line to request password...

Comment: you have all of the logic to read the account no in the catch block of your try catch move it into the try block.

Comment: I fixed your indentation; in future, please indent your source correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your main function ...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
        { 
            try 
            {     
                File fXmlFile = new File(".xml");  
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();   
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);        
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();          
                NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");   

                System.out.println("============================================");
                System.out.println("==========Welcome to Multiuser ATM=========="); 
                System.out.println("============================================\n\n"); 
                System.out.println("Please enter your Account Number:"); 
                int acno = sc.nextInt();       
                System.out.println("Please enter your Password:");  
                int password = sc.nextInt();        
                System.out.println("Your Account Balance is:"); 
                System.out.println("Please choose your option:"); 

    //------------You just have to insert below code---------------------

                for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++)
                {
                    Node nNode =  nList.item(temp);

                    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
                    {
                        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                        int ano = Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("acno", eElement));
                        System.out.println("ANO:  "+ano);
                        if(ano == acno)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Acno:    "+acno+"  ANO:  "+ano);
                            int pass = Integer.parseInt(getTagValue("password", eElement));
                            if(pass == password)
                                System.out.println("Password:    "+password+"  pass:  "+pass);
                        }                   
                    }
                }
            }   
            catch (Exception e)  
            {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
```